# Unable to plot a pandas dataframe using the built-in plotter

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
    created_date        client_name amount  timestamp
0   2019-03-17 08:48:36 ABC         156.89  2019-03-17 08:48:36
1   2019-03-17 08:48:13 ABC         563.62  2019-03-17 08:48:13
2   2019-03-17 08:47:45 ABC         126.92  2019-03-17 08:47:45
3   2019-03-16 13:58:11 XYZ         292.71  2019-03-16 13:58:11
4   2019-03-16 10:01:28 EFG         180.41  2019-03-16 10:01:28
```

and when I try to use the built-in `plot()` method:

```
ax = df.loc[df.client_name == 'ABC'].plot(x=['timestamp'], y=['amount'])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: x must be a label or position
```

I have done this with Bokeh before, but now I have to do it using the built-in plotter. What would be the correct way to get this to work?

Comment: the `timestamp` column is converted to proper date and time.

Comment: You might try `... .plot(x='timestamp', y='amount')` without the square brackets.

Comment: Then I get `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`

Comment: I suspect this is because of the index, I guess I can feed the timestamp into the index but I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Try `print(df['amount'])` and check that it is of dtype: float64.  If it is object, you need to convert the amount column.  `df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype(float)`

Comment: Yes! @JohanC, df['amount'] was indeed an Object. I have missed an error while cleaning up the data and there was a `string` inside the `amount` values. Thanks.

Comment: I have added my answer, but please feel free to re-post as it is your answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @JohanC pointed, the `df['amount']` was not a clean `float`, there were some strings in there so the `print(df['amount'])` test was returning an `object`. Once that was fixed, the initial solution worked:

```
ax = df.loc[df.client_name == 'ABC'].plot(x='timestamp', y='amount')
```